# TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata

Tags: fedora

I want to switch from Ubuntu 16.04 to Fedora 27,
so I made a bootable USB, but it always shows the
error in the title.

I tried for hours to solve it, also installed
intel-microcode, but nothing seem to work.

Does someone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: Thank you. It seems that UNetbootin made a mistake. With Etcher it works.

Comment: @Rabbitrun For that reason, we (Fedora) recommend using Fedora Media Writer rather than unetbootin or other software, which often does the wrong thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my solution to fixing this error on an Ubuntu Live USB

https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/7nx165/firmware_bug_tsc_deadline_disabled/dt6d0mm/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now it doesn't show the firmware error, but after a delay bunch of dracut-initqueue timeouts and than a terminal/emergency mode.